# Symfony- Authenticating against LDAPserver

Tags: symfony, openldap

I am trying to authenticate my users against an `LDAP` servr.

```
security:
    providers:
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: 'DC=maxcrc,DC=com'
                search_dn: 'CN=manager,DC=maxcrc,DC=com'
                search_password: 'secret'
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
...
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~

            form_login_ldap:
                #http_basic_ldap:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: 'maxcrc\{username}'

my services.yml:

...

    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
        arguments:
        -   host: localhost
            port: 389
            #encryption: tls
            options:
                protocol_version: 3
                referrals: false`
```

It seems to perfectly follow symfony intructions.. I can bind to my server,, however I get invalid credentials error whenever I submit my form!! 
Please assist accordingly!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [`uid_key`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html#uid-key) in your ldap definition:

```yaml
security:
    providers:
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: 'DC=maxcrc,DC=com'
                search_dn: 'CN=manager,DC=maxcrc,DC=com'
                search_password: 'secret'
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: 'samaccountname'
```

Apart from that, I have these settings:

```yaml
    firewalls:
      dev:
          pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false
      main:
          anonymous: ~
          form_login_ldap:
              service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
              login_path: login
              check_path: login
              dn_string: '%env(ADLDAP_BASEDN)%'
              query_string: '(samaccountname={username})'
          logout:
              path: /logout
              target: login
```

Relevant would be the `dn_string` and the `query_string`. Not sure if all that is nessecary, this is my first time using symfony.

`ADLDAP_BASEDN` is defined in my `.env` file as:

```
ADLDAP_BASEDN=DC=blah,DC=example,DC=com
```

**edit**
Sorry, I misread your question, somehow I thought you authenticate against an Active Directory. With openldap the uid key should be `uid`, which is most probably the default. But your dn_string looks wrong to me, and maybe `query_string` is needed as well. I'll edit the answer accordingly tomorrow when I'm not on my phone.

Comment: many thanks for your feedback Gerald!! i am desperately looking for some assistance since 3 days!! gonna wait for your tomorrow's comment.